# Double integral for a region

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the following double integral
$$∫∫_R9x^3ydA$$
where R is the rectangle with vertices (0,0), (2,0), (0,6), and (2,6).

can some one help show me how to set up this double integral? I have a good understanding of double integrals and how to solve them I am just not good at this whole regions thing. I cant ever seem to set them up right. can anyone help me with the problem and really explain how they interpreted the region and came up with the points for the integration, thank you so much

Comment: The region for integration is $0\leq x\leq 2$ and $0\leq y \leq 6$. If this is not clear, draw a picture and see how things look like.

Comment: Draw the region neatly and carefully on graph paper. This is an easier one, since the boundaries are all parallel to the axes.

Comment: @TonyK oh yeah thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The domain of integration is normal, so that you can compute it via an iterated integral:
$$
\int_R 9x^3 y \, dx \, dy =
\int_0^2 \left( 
\int_0^6 9x^3 y \, dy
\right) \, dx.
$$

Comment: the question asked for a detailed explanation of the limits, and is obviously from someone who has probably struggled with more complicated setups, so it might be nice to explain in detail why your limits are so nice and why you don't have to consider other things.

Comment: Not easy... I teach a course in which the double integral over a rectangle is *defined* via an interated integral. So we should also know what definition the OP starts with...

Comment: fair point, but i think the elementary intuition version is what the OP is looking for.